# Why does this happen for a single 's'

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML form that has a field

```
<div style="width:100px; padding-top:10px;margin-left:10px;float:left;" align="left">Your Username:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div>
```

Now when I'm trying to validate the form using javacript like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#smbt").click(function(){
            if ($("#username").val()=="") {
                alert("Field is empty.");
            } else {
                alert("You are ok.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above program works fine but a strange thing happens when I change the div id to "usernames" and name to "usernames" like this

```
<input type="text" id="usernames" name="usernames" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs">
```

As soon as I do the above line the program starts giving wrong output. Like if the username textfield is empty it pops up the alert message "You are ok" and if not it still pops the alert message "You are ok". But as soon as I change id="username" name="username" the program runs correctly. Why is this happening because of an 's'

Comment: did you change `$('#username')` to `$('#usernames')` too?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your jQuery to match the ID change. It's looking for "username" when then ID is "usernames", so the statement is false.

```
if ($("#username").val()=="") {
```

Should be

```
if ($("#usernames").val()=="") {
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you change this one too ?

```
$("#username").val()
```

to

```
$("#usernames").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `id` of the field to `usernames`, `$("#username").val()` will result in `undefined` which is different from an empty string. So you need to change the jQuery selector too.

If you want to deal with `undefined` and empty strings you can change the test to:

```
if (!$("#username").val()) {
    alert("Field is empty.");
} else {
    alert("You are ok.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because username is not found on the actual page.

JQuery selectors return an array of matched aleements. So val becomes undefined.

Which is not equal to "" therefore your code enter the else clause.

HTH